# Run pipeline in parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a pipeline that I need to run in parallel on two nodes. I was wondering what the best way is to accomplish this? The two nodes are **U60 and SCA**.

```
pipeline 
{
    agent { label 'U60 && SCA' }

    stages
    {
        stage ('Test')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    def test_proj_choices = ['AD', 'CD', 'DC', 'DISP_A', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO15', 'SYSIO42', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA']
                    for (choice in test_proj_choices) 
                    {
                        stage ("${choice}") 
                        {
                            echo "Running ${choice}"
                            build job: "UH60Job", parameters: [string(name: "TEST_PROJECT", value: choice), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: Doesn't really help me. I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this in my pipeline. When I try surrounding a stage with a parallel block, I get an error.

Comment: Do you want to run the whole pipeline in parallel on two nodes?

Comment: yes, the whole pipleline needs to run in parallel on two nodes.